# Clear the screen before next frame in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, move

I know I cannot use `context.clearRect()` in three.js without a canvas and stuff. But my q is:      **How can I implement what clearRect does but in Three.js WebGLRenderer?**

I have a game that moves a json model all the time, and its last position is ALSO drawn. (and every position before that)

How to do?? :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to implement it. It is already there. Use

```
renderer.setClearColor (0x000000, 1);
```

and before each frame is drawn, the color that you specify will be used to clear the canvas.